# The problem about ROC curve and threshold in R

Tags: r, probability, roc, threshold, kappa

I have some data about the occurrence of turtles in different temperature and I use glm() to calculate the predicted probability of occurrence in each temperature. Then I plot ROC curve and max kappa. What does max kappa mean? What does the x axis of max kappa plot mean? Is there any relationship between these two figures?

```
> glm_eval<-evaluate(predict_presence,predict_absence,model=glm_model)
> max_kappa <- plogis(threshold(glm_eval, stat='kappa'))
> par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
> plot(glm_eval, 'ROC', type='l')  
> plot(glm_eval,'kappa', type='l',xlim=c(-30,5))  
> abline(v=max_kappa, lty=2,col='blue')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9QWO.png)

Comment: It would be good to include a a sample of your input dataset, also, `threshold` seems to come from a specific library. Consider to include at the top of you code all the required libraries you are using. Also, please, consider reviewing how to make an r reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Evaluate? Threshold? These aren't standard R functions. Please make sure you state all the libraries you are  using.